# Passing multiple parameters into MongoDB query method

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

How i can pass multiple parameters in mongodb

My current setup is like this:

```
const query = (...query) => {

let newQuery = query // this is an array
    Model.findByIdAndUpdate(newQuery) // nothing happen coz the value is array 
}

query(id, {name:'json bourne'})
```

I want to pass the all the parameters on the query. Thanks

The original query is this 
`Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { name: 'jason bourne' })`

Is to pass the parameters like this

`let newQuery = 
id, { name: 'jason bourne'}// this will not work also it on get the first item which is id`

`Model.findByIdAndUpdate(newQuery)`

Comment: Why not just `{ id, name: 'json bourne'}` ?

Comment: That will not work as id, and name is a separate object see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate

Comment: Your question is not self explanatory please explain it  better so that we can help you out

Comment: Here is the original query `Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { name: 'jason bourne' })`

Comment: So tell me what exactly do you want to do with this

Comment: i am assuming you want to update your query according to params you receive from the request.

Answer (score 1):

You destruct the array to get what you want

```js
const query = (...query) => {

let [id, update, options = {}] = query // this is an array
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, options) // nothing happen coz the value is array

}
```

But in this case, it will be equivalent to

```js
const query = (id, update, options = {}) => {
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, options) // nothing happen coz the value is array
}
```

Which is, again, equivalent to

```js
const query = Model.findByIdAndUpdate;
```

Comment: Thanks. This will work if you know and how many you are passing. What if you have not just two or three parameters.

Comment: well, `Model.findByIdAndUpdate()` takes 3 params and you have to pass at least two of them. thats why on my code, I am failing back the 3rd param to default `{}`

Comment: What i did so far is this

Answer (score 0):

`Model.findByIdAndUpdate` requires atleast 2 arguments. First is the `id` itself which is required to find the document to update. And second argument is the `options` which is an object which contains the key-pair values of the fields that you want to update in that document. Here the key will be the field that needs to be updated and its value will be the value you wish the field to have. You can have as many key-pairs as you want as long as they are comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

You could just spread the array:

```
 Model.findByIdAndUpdate(...newQuery)
```